# How do I install swell-foop-3.11.1.tar.gz in Linux Mint Petra?

Tags: linux-mint

How do I install `swell-foop-3.11.1.tar.gz` in Linux Mint Petra?
I tried to install it with software manager but the game does not seem to work, so I downloaded  `swell-foop-3.11.1.tar.gz` and extracted it, but I don't know how to install it.
Do I use terminal? If so how?

Comment: Why aren't you using a package manager? Does `apt-get install swell-foop` not work?

Comment: I tried apt-get install swell-foopE: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?

Comment: I tried apt-get install swell-foop                     got message in terminal    E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), are you root?   I am root it didnot ask for password    I also clicked on autogen.sh   a terminal quickly opened and closed but I cannot see a game anywhere   there was no README or INSTALL

Comment: Is it possible that you have `/var` on a read-only partition (a terrible idea, if that's the case!)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your answer to my comment, it seems you're unaware that Swell Foop can be installed directly from the repos. Of course trying the installation as a regular user will fail. To install as root, follow these steps:

```
[user@host]$ su
Password:
[root@host]# apt-get install swell-foop
```

This of course assumes you have root access. If you haven't enabled the root account during installation, do this instead:

```
[user@host]$ sudo apt-get install swell-foop
[sudo] password for user:
```

Note that in this second case, you should use your regular user password.

Comment: I copied and pasted in terminal and got message [user@host]$ su
[user@host]$: command not found

Comment: Joseph R.
thankyou for you comments and advice I am Dsylexic so have trouble reading  and typing so I try to copy and paste please excuse my bad typing
I will try and reinstall Petra tommorrow and post my question again 
thankyou for trying to help goodnight

Comment: @markhewpac No worries. I don't see why you're going for a fresh install, though. Has something major happened to your installation? Also, you probably have already seen this, but I'll put it here just in case it can help you or someone else: [opendyslexic.org](http://opendyslexic.org/).

Comment: thankyou for the url Joseph R 
I just have downloaded it

done a reinstall of mint Petra Mate 64 bit
cut and pasted your commands but still asks if 
I am root?

Comment: @markhewpac _are_ you root? What do you get when you type `id` after entering your root password?

Comment: Joseph R. thankyou for your assistance I am a Dsyslexic dickhead       I was copying [user@host]$  with my copy function then pasting into Terminal Duh!!!  swell-foop is now working when i tried Software manager game would not work     using your commands in terminal correctly game has installed and working thank you Joseph R.

Comment: @markhewpac Glad I could be of help. If this solved your problem, please consider marking the answer "Accepted" so that others know that the problem has been solved.

Comment: How do I add solved to my post?

Comment: @markhewpac You simply mark the answer that helped you accepted by clicking on the tick mark below the vote count on its left.

Comment: @markhewpac Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

First we need to determine what type of archive it is (since tar can hold any type of file). The three most common types of software distribution by tar file are source archives, installer archives, and package archives. Source archives contain the source code of the program, not the executable. Both of the other types contain the executable. these days it is more common for packages with executables to include the architecture in the file name (swell-foop-3.11.1-i386.tar.gz) but not always. So lets see if they tell us. we start by looking for a file called README or INSTALL. If you have them this is where to start. If not lets look fore a file called configure or makefile or any file ending in a .c. If you find any of these its a source archive, and will need compiled. so you want to ask that frequently asked question, "How do I compile swell foop?" which is a much bigger question than I am answering.

Now if it has a file called something like installer.sh or similar it is probably an installer archive that has a script to put the files where they need to be. this should documented in the readme.

If it has directories like usr lib bin etc usr/bin and so fourth It is probably intended to be extracted in your root directory like a slackware package.